# I need put next line inside popup javascript String with java value

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I need do a next line into a popup javascript with String with java values.

My string values look like this:

```
var sText="Random text:"+"<%= object.getAtt%>""\n";
```

I can't do that becouse when java is converted a normal value for browser reader, the browser read a javascript code like this:

```
var sText="Random text a1
a2
a3
a4
"
```

And when i try show the popup:

```
alert(sText);
```

The result is : **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

You can append your `result` using `+` so that your result will appear in `new line` i.e :

```
var sText="";
for(..){
 sText + ="Random text:"+"<%= object.getAtt%>"+"\n";   
    //^ appending result
}
alert(sText);
```

With sample data :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var sText="";
btn.onclick = function(){

for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
sText +="Random text:"+i+"\n";
     //^ appending result
 alert(sText); 
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click me !"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sText="Random text a1 \n b1 \n c1 \n d1"

alert("Hello World"+sText)
```

```html
Hello World.
```

```
Hello World
```

You can run this program, add \n newline